# C Programming On Windows - For Someone Who Used To Do It On Ubuntu

Tags: c, windows, unix, gcc

**Backstory:** I have searched around and read some questions from SO, but I am still somewhat confused.

I learnt C at University, only been here 1 semester and we're on break.

I learnt to program in C under a Unix environment, Mac OS X and Ubuntu and it was dead easy.

Open terminal, install GCC, start using vim and writing some make files for your projects and you're done.

I have removed my Ubuntu partition since I only used it for C programming, I am too grounded in Windows (games etc...) and I am looking for a similar experience on Windows.

I don't particularly want to install anything from .NET at all, since it's never just the application, but 500000 other useless things - which pisses me off to be honest.

---

**TL;DR;**

I heard MinGW was using an extremely old version of gcc and isn't maintained, otherwise I would be using that.

**So does anyone know of a gcc, no nonsense port or otherwise for C programming on Windows?**

**I can use Notepad++ for writing the .c files and syntax hilighting, I don't care about an IDE at all.**

Comment: Why don't you use Eclipse for windows?

Comment: Visual C++ Express gives you a free C/C++ toolchain + debugger that is sure to be maintained and is trivial to install

Comment: I'm afraid you're fairly out of luck.  I've always thought it rather ridiculous that on Windows platforms, you need about 8 gigabytes' worth of disk space to install Visual Studio, just to compile "hello, world".

Comment: @simonc... He doesn't want to use MS tools.

Comment: I can not understand what's wrong with mingw? Underlying compiler in latest mingw is gcc 4.7.2, that is newest stable.

Comment: @sgar91 I didn't see that in his question.  He wants to develop in C on Windows.  The easiest way to do this is to use the standard tool for that platform - Visual Studio.  Depending on your interpretation of the vague requirement to avoid unused .NET installs, VS for C++ may be just as valid as mingw.

Comment: @sheu - I know right? Microsoft needs to stop trying to defy standards, like with IE, and use things which are tried and true.

Comment: I use MinGW and have absolutely no problem with it: http://www.mingw.org . The MSYS runtime has been updated end of 2012 so it is maintained though. You will have a feeling to be home just at begin as a Linux user.

Comment: @Konstantin Vladimirov - Is that the case? This may be solved then. Thanks as well **duDE.**

Comment: MinGW latest version is 4.7.2 - matching GCC's most recent version. A simple search could have revealed those inaccuracies and myths you were told.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using MinGW now - I was informed incorrectly about it using an outdated version of GCC.

In a way, I suppose I deserve the down votes for not checking myself.

Oh well, you live and learn.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would probably be to install cygwin (you may need to explicitly select "gcc" from the development section).  If you had worked on unix, it would probably be a good idea to cygwin on your windows machine anyways.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an IDE such as visual studio that will bundle all the needed features (compiler, libraries, etc)

If you don't want to bother with an IDE and prefer the lightness of vim, installing it on windows and compiling in the CLI is a pain, Cygwin is cool (see other answer) but I can't bear the windows terminal compared to the Linux / Mac ones.

Maybe consider using a Virtual Machine running Ubuntu for all your development.

Comment: Windows terminal is a joke frankly - may look into MinGW since someone said it actually uses the latest gcc.

Comment: Visual studio has a broken C89 compiler at best - nothing more.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is NO.

You either use MinGW, or you use Visual Studio. There is no **lightweight** third option, unless you want to use Turbo C.

Comment: Eclipse is an IDE, not a compiler, and it uses MinGW for its compiler anyway. And it's not lightweight.

Comment: What is its compiler? Besides, Cygwin is not very lightweight. He wants something GCC based, and he doesn't want unneeded dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

- CodeBlocks:
  http://www.codeblocks.org/
- Eclipse, as someone mentioned earlier too;
  -older versions of programs are good for learning too like:
  Borland C++ 3.1
  Turbo C
  (both DOS based)

Try Visual studio 6.0 :)
no .NET on that release.